# DateTimeFormatter unable to parse formatted date

Tags: java, java-time

I use DateTimeFormatter to format a date. This works but when I try to convert this formatted date back to a date I get an exception.

Code:

```
DateTimeFormatter weekOfYear = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("w/yyyy");

LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
String dateString = weekOfYear.format(localDate);

localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, weekOfYear);
```

Exception when I try to parse it:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '50/2019' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2019, WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=50},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2020)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1955)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
    at DateTimeFormatterTest.weekOfYear(DateTimeFormatterTest.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2019, WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=50},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.from(LocalDate.java:396)
    at java.base/java.time.format.Parsed.query(Parsed.java:235)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1951)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: That is very interesting!! How come, their own example from the documentation doesn't work depending from the format?! It is valid to generate, but not retrieve back! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: @Brother See my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The date cannot be parsed because the day part was missing.

So I had to set the default for the dayOfWeek:

```
DateTimeFormatter weekOfYear = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("w/YYYY")
            .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1).toFormatter();
```

Comment: You have also changed lowercase `yyyy` for year to uppercase `YYYY` for week-based year, which is a necessary part of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it's an expected behaviour.
We couldn't guess an exact date based on the week number and year.

You could specify what are you trying to do so anyone could help.